# NullPointerException during bean creation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I'm receiving a NullPointerException in a method with the Annotation `@Bean`, but before I never got this NullPointerException there:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dev.teamnight.command.CommandFramework]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'config' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'commandFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.Config.commandFramework(Config.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d4937ec.CGLIB$commandFramework$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d4937ec$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3fbdfefd.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d4937ec.commandFramework(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 69 common frames omitted
```

The code of the file causing the Exception:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:bot.properties")
public class Config {
    @Autowired
    private ShardManager shardManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private PermissionProvider permissionProvider;
    @Autowired
    private LanguageProvider languageProvider;
    @Autowired
    private PrefixProvider prefixProvider;
    @Autowired
    private HelpProvider helpProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public ShardManager shardManager() throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {
        DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = DefaultShardManagerBuilder.createDefault(this.botToken)
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE)
                .setShardsTotal(this.totalShards)
                .addEventListeners(Arrays.asList(this.jdaListener()));
        
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandFramework commandFramework() {
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
        //Line causing the error below!
        log.error("Name of helpProvider: " + this.helpProvider.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return new FrameworkBuilder()
                .addOwners(Arrays.stream(this.ownerIds).filter(ownerId -> ownerId.matches("^(\\d)+$")).map(ownerId -> Long.parseLong(ownerId)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setLogger(NightBot.logger())
                .allowBots(false)
                .allowDM(false)
                .allowMention(true)
                .allowRainbowColors(true)
                .withPrefixProvider(this.prefixProvider)
                .withLanguageProvider(this.languageProvider)
                .withPermissionProvider(this.permissionProvider)
                .withHelpProvider(this.helpProvider)
                .withCustomArgumentProcessor(new NamedArgumentProcessor())
                .registerClient(this.shardManager)
                .build();
    }
}
```

As I said, before the code fully worked, and I changed nothing on the Config.java file, so this error is confusing me as hell.

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and check what exactly is null there.

Comment: @szatkus this.helpProvider is null

Comment: @Nightloewe I've made a few assumptions based on the information you provided to answer your question. stacktrace, the fact that you haven't touched your `Config` class. I'd recommend looking through your commit logs to see if the `Config` has been autowired into any new places -- or CommandFramework is also the likely culprit

Comment: This is *extremely* odd and looks like it should work fine. I will note that it is generally a good idea to inject dependencies as method parameters instead of fields, and this might solve (or clarify) the problem.

Comment: Remove the autowired `shardManager` and instead of `this.shardManager` do `this.shardManager()`. Call the method instead. This will solve your eager init of the config and `CommandFramework` and remove the circular dependency. As a rule of thumb, don't autowire a bean in a class that also creates it (that will lead to issues somewhere down the road).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this `NullPointerException` because the autowired `HelperProvider` not being injected in.

You are attempting to call `.getClass()` on a null object.

#### General Dependency Injection Debugging

Just want to add a quick basic mentions, since the main answer to this question has to make some assumption on your codebase. There are several things that you want to check when dependency injection fails.

1. Configuration files - Are these being loaded in correctly. Is your component scanning recently disabled?
2. Do your `Components` have the necessary `@Component` and or `@Service/@Controller/@Repository` annotations?

## The Likely Root Problem - Circular Reference - BeanInstantiationException

There is also a mention of a circular reference in your stacktrace which is likely what is causing the problem.

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Circular reference involving containing bean 'config' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'commandFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Since you received this error message, you have introduced a circular reference. This means... that a component relies on a component which relies on that component.

For example:

```
@Component
class HelperProvider {
   @Autowired
   Config config;
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
class Config {
   @Autowired
   HelperProvider helperProvider
}
```

This pattern will stump the spring framework because they rely on each other to load each component up. It can happen if you introduce a dependency further down the line. Say HelperProvider requires HelperHelperProvider which requires Config.

You will want to check for any new injections of `Config` or `CommandFramework` in your recent edits.

## What you should do

You will want to redesign your configuration to break it's reliance on the `HelperProvider`. Doing this can resolve a lot of headaches in your future.

## What you shouldn't do

It's possible to lazyload the component or configuration with `@Lazy` annotation. That way the bean is only instantiated upon invocation. It's recommended if you want to learn more nuances in booting up the Spring `ApplicationContext`, but it will become a nightmare to maintain down the road.

Comment: I checked my commits and found out that I added the CommandFramework as a dependency to the JDA Listener used for the ShardManager. The CommandFramework needs the ShardManager bean to be created and so this created the circular reference which caused the HelpProvider to not be created. I believe this is the problem and should leave a note in the code, that all objects needed for the CommandFramework and ShardManager need to be checked for references on them.

Comment: But what should I do if I ever run into the problem that some objects rely on each other and I can't change the code easily to fix this?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is setting up two different configs. One to create the `ShardManager` bean and one to create the `CommandFramework` bean. They both depend on different components to build. And would be a step in removing chances of circular dependency.

Comment: There is also the `@Order` or `@DependsOn` annotation if you want to specify a bean creation order. I still would not recommend this approach

Comment: The `ShardManager` depends on the `JDAListener` and the `JDAListener` on the `CommandFramework`. But the `CommandFramework` also depends on the `ShardManager`.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the following dependency: CommandFramework -> config.PrefixProvider -> Housekeeper -> Config -> config.PrefixProvider, which was unable to create, because config.jdaListener asked for CommandFramework, so the problem was not HelpProvider, but the Config object

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is most probably because you have a cyclic dependency in your project. And since you are getting it in **commandFramework** method as illustrated in error it is because of the HelpProvider class in which you are using the Config class again.

So when spring is creating a bean of Config it has to create a bean of HelpProvider which in terms wants to create a bean of Config(Autowired in HelpProvider) and leads to a never ending cycle giving the error. Also check if HelpProvider has the @component annotataion.

Config -> HelpProvider -> Config -> HelpProvider -> Config .............

Solution:-

1. Either you can remove the config from the HelpProvider and try to redesign it.
2. Use @Lazy on Config in HelpProvider which will load this dependency on object instantiation. Will suggest it as a last resort.